# Why are our Android Crashlytics callstacks inaccurate?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

We're using Firebase 10.7.0 in a Unity il2cpp project. Crashes and exceptions show up in Crashlytics. Exceptions work as expected. However, the crash callstacks are inaccurate - they don't match what Unity's crash reporter shows, and furthermore don't seem to have any libil2cpp.so or libunity.so entries in any thread.

By having the application purposefully crash, we can verify that the callstack looks correct in Unity crash diagnostics:

```
Thread 0 (crashed)
0   libc.so                            0x00000000f3e64bac <symbols missing for uuid: 13bc715234d0861084dc092396cf9938> 
1   libunity.so                        0x00000000b43a54e1 Utils_CUSTOM_ForceCrash(DiagnosticsUtils_Bindings::ForcedCrashCategory) 
2   libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000045b71ec (unknown) (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\UnityEngine.CoreModule__3.cpp:0)
3   libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b3a431f0 UnityEvent_Invoke_mFBF80D59B03C30C5FE6A06F897D954ACADE061D2 (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\UnityEngine.CoreModule__3.cpp:15108)
4   libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000045b71ec (unknown) (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\UnityEngine.CoreModule__3.cpp:0)
5   libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b3a431f0 UnityEvent_Invoke_mFBF80D59B03C30C5FE6A06F897D954ACADE061D2 (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\UnityEngine.CoreModule__3.cpp:15108)
6   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000000198c63c EventFunction_1_Invoke_m98A8A653E7180305E41F7CFFDDD9D32C63B96FE7_gshared_inline (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\GenericMethods__34.cpp:44326)
7   libil2cpp.so                       0x000000000198c630 EventFunction_1_Invoke_m98A8A653E7180305E41F7CFFDDD9D32C63B96FE7_inline (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\GenericMethods__34.cpp:15124)
8   libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b0e18644 ExecuteEvents_Execute_TisRuntimeObject_mDC4455B743BE4A6BA46DD741D0E0AB150FF1209A_gshared (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\GenericMethods__34.cpp:42151)
9   libil2cpp.so                       0x0000000004101004 ExecuteEvents_Execute_TisIPointerClickHandler_t77341AA19DE37C26F5F619DE8BD28B70D5A2B5D8_m024FB23AA1DBB1B7A5E1935FA35A1E4FF57AC5F6 (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Unity.InputSystem__6.cpp:5169)
10  libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b358d008 InputSystemUIInputModule_ProcessPointerButton_m68284C737796E80096AD8EAD1E0C687577131FE6 (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Unity.InputSystem__6.cpp:8033)
11  libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b358c590 InputSystemUIInputModule_ProcessPointer_mD889935190247CE78A8FE68ACA10CDD1C3B43E5D (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Unity.InputSystem__6.cpp:6936)
12  libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b3592c50 InputSystemUIInputModule_Process_mD46ECAA34DE552BF7178B12774FDF80ED24FB980 (C:/workspace/workspace/p/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Unity.InputSystem__6.cpp:13692)
13  libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b076b344 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::InvokeWithThrow(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) 
14  libil2cpp.so                       0x00000000b076b284 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**) 
15  libunity.so                        0x00000000b4566e09 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) 
16  libunity.so                        0x00000000b45725bd ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) 
17  libunity.so                        0x00000000b457c455 MonoBehaviour::CallUpdateMethod(int) 
18  libunity.so                        0x00000000b4420a29 void BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>() 
19  libunity.so                        0x00000000b44b537f ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) 
20  libunity.so                        0x00000000b44b53a1 ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) 
21  libunity.so                        0x00000000b44b5583 PlayerLoop() 
22  libunity.so                        0x00000000b45cd87b UnityPlayerLoop() 
23  libunity.so                        0x00000000b45de387 nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*) 
24  base.odex                          0x00000000c73869cb <symbols missing for uuid: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000>
```

The Firebase callstack for the same crash instance, however, looks like this:

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV  0x0000000000001d86
#00 pc 0x9fbac libc.so (BuildId: 13bc715234d0861084dc092396cf9938)
#01 pc 0xbf7ffffe
```

When I download the full stack trace, libil2cpp.so doesn't show up IN ANY THREAD. Neither does libunity.so. It's all libc.so/libutils.so/libart.so/libmonochrome.so.It's almost like the Crashlytics trace is from a different process. The only hint that it's actually a Unity executable is there are some libunitytuningfork.so references in a few threads.

Notably, iOS crashes in Crashlytics are perfect - it's just the Android ones that are wrong.

We'd be happy to keep using the Unity crash dashboard, however it doesn't show every thread for Android crashes(only the one that crashed) so it's less useful for multithreaded issues. Would really love to get Crashlytics working properly - anybody seen something similar?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure, are you generating and uploading symbols every time you build for Android?

This step is done automatically as part of the iOS build process but [must be run for every Android build](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=unity#build-project-upload-symbols).

If you have not been doing that, give it a try, see how it changes what you see and how well the results match your expectations.